# Rename document without closing UIDocument

Tags: ios, uikit, uidocument

**How do I rename a document file with an open UIDocument without closing and reopening the document?** Closing (saving), moving, and reopening the document takes too long.

I have the following code that moves the file:

```
NSFileCoordinator* fileCoordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:nil];
[fileCoordinator coordinateWritingItemAtURL:oldPath
                                    options:NSFileCoordinatorWritingForMoving
                           writingItemAtURL:newPath
                                    options:NSFileCoordinatorWritingForReplacing
                                      error:&coordinatorError
                                 byAccessor:^(NSURL *newURL1, NSURL *newURL2) {
  // Rename the file.
  NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
  [fileCoordinator itemAtURL:oldPath willMoveToURL:newPath];
  [fileManager moveItemAtURL:newURL1 toURL:newURL2 error:nil];
  [fileCoordinator itemAtURL:oldPath didMoveToURL:newPath];
}];
```

According to the documentation `UIDocument` implements `presentedItemDidMoveToURL:` to update its `fileURL` (see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocument_Class/)

However, when the above code is called with the document open, it hangs, presumably waiting for a lock on `oldPath` (`-[NSFileCoordinator(NSPrivate) _blockOnAccessClaim:]`). Works fine if there is no living `UIDocument`.

Related, top answer suggests to close and reopen the `UIDocument`: [What is the proper way to move a UIDocument to a new location on the file-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284137/what-is-the-proper-way-to-move-a-uidocument-to-a-new-location-on-the-file-system)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution was to use a background queue to avoid the deadlock:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {

  NSError *coordinatorError = nil;

  NSFileCoordinator* fileCoordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:nil];
  [fileCoordinator coordinateWritingItemAtURL:oldPath
                                    options:NSFileCoordinatorWritingForMoving
                           writingItemAtURL:newPath
                                    options:NSFileCoordinatorWritingForReplacing
                                      error:&coordinatorError
                                 byAccessor:^(NSURL *newURL1, NSURL *newURL2) {
    // Rename the file.
    NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [fileCoordinator itemAtURL:oldPath willMoveToURL:newPath];
    [fileManager moveItemAtURL:newURL1 toURL:newURL2 error:nil];
    [fileCoordinator itemAtURL:oldPath didMoveToURL:newPath];
  }];

});
```